# implement parallel execute in scheme

Tags: concurrency, scheme, sicp

In SICP section 3.4 (serializers in scheme) on Currency there is a procedure called parallel-execute that is described but not implemented in MIT scheme. I wonder if anyone has actually implemented it; if not how would one get started in implementing such procedure?

http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-23.html#%_sec_3.4.1

Comment: To implement that one would build it at the meta-circular interpreter level.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I implemented `parallel-execute` for solving the exercises in section 3.4 of SICP, using Racket:

```
(define (parallel-execute . procs)
  (map thread-wait
       (map (lambda (proc) (thread proc))
            procs)))
```

I can't guarantee that it has the same semantics as the `parallel-execute` procedure defined in the book, but it allowed me to solve the exercises.

Comment: @Mark waiting 'till all threads have finished their jobs before continuing with execution

Comment: In order to see changes to the accounts in sicp 3.4 section, you must run the balance procedure after using parallel-execute. Procedures that run in background threads won't display return values like when they're run on the main thread.

Comment: This works perfectly in Racket.

Answer (score 7):

This book's official site offers a implement [parallel.scm](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/ps7/readme.html).
Open MIT Scheme like this:

```
mit-scheme -load PATH/parallel.scm
```

or put this

```
(load "PATH/parallel.scm")
```

at the head of your scheme source file.

Comment: link broken as of april 2018. working link to parallel.scm [can be found here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/psets/ps7/readme.html)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can load all the necessary implementations in racket with the following package. Just type this in either the definitions or the interactions window and the necessary package will be installed and when you need it, include the same comment in the definitions window:

(require (planet dyoo/sicp-concurrency:1:2/sicp-concurrency))

Answer (score 2):

In GNU Guile the procedure is implemented as `parallel`. It is there defined as a special form and available from `(use-modules (ice-9 threads))`. If you want to implement it yourself, you may have a look at the source code of this module.